# Sum the unique numbers in a list

Tags: code-golf, math, arithmetic

For this challenge, the objective is to take a list of integers, and output the sum of every unique integer in that list, i.e. count multiples of the same integer only once.
Your input will be a string in the format `"{1,2,3,4}"` with any amount of elements. The string will never have whitespace or be in a format that does not match the example above. **A list with 0 elements should return `0`.**

### Examples

```
"{1,2,3,4}" -> 10
"{5,2,5}" -> 7
"{13,13,13}" -> 13
"{-5,5,5}" -> 0
"{12,12,13,13,14,14}" -> 39
"{}" -> 0
"{3}" -> 3
```

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest answer in bytes wins.

Good luck!

Comment: In the future, please use the [Sandbox](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/2140/sandbox-for-proposed-challenges?cb=1) to allow your challenges to get feedback before posting them on the main site.

Comment: Why the strict input format?

Comment: Since I dislike downvotes without comments, I'll explain why I downvoted, and hopefully provide some constructive criticism for your next challenge. 1) This challenge is very trivial in the vast majority of languages and 2) demanding that the input comes in a rigid string form makes it unnecessarily complicated for some languages that have do extra parsing for no good reason.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 1 [byte](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
S
```

**[TryItOnline](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=Uw&input=&args=ezEyLDEyLDEzLDEzLDE0LDE0fQ)**

Since command line arguments are passed as a string to Python, it evaluates as a set*.
`S` then sums the resulting list Jelly will receive.

* except in the empty case (as pointed out by @Dennis) when `"{}"` evaluates to an empty dictionary, but this gets cast to a list of it's keys, which is an empty list.

Answer (score 6):

### Python 2, <s>21</s> 18 bytes:

```
print sum(input())
```

Comment: Nice job muddyfish :)

Comment: Why would this work? `sum([1,1,1])=3`, not 1

Comment: The input format is python's default for a set. A set automatically removes duplicates

Answer (score 4):

## [MATL](http://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 4 bytes

```
Ugus
```

String delimiter in MATL is `'`.

[Try it online!](http://matl.tryitonline.net/#code=VWd1cw&input=J3sxMiwxMiwxMywxMywxNCwxNH0n)

#### Explanation

```
U    % Implicitly input string and evaluate it. Gives a cell array
g    % Convert to vector
u    % Unique
s    % Sum. Implicitly display
```

Comment: @JonathanAllan Whoops. It does now. Thanks!

Comment: Sounds like something a caveman might say haha! `Ugus!Ugus!Ugus!`

Answer (score 2):

### JavaScript (ES6), 61 bytes

```
s=>[...new Set(s.slice(1,-1).split`,`)].reduce((s,n)=>+n+s,0)
```

Without the unreasonable input format it's only 39 bytes:

```
f=a=>[...new Set(a)].reduce((s,n)=>s+n,0)
```

The `,0` is necessary to work with an empty array.

Comment: Doesn't work for me...

Answer (score 2):

### Actually, 2 bytes

```
≡Σ
```

[Try it online!](http://actually.tryitonline.net/#code=4omhzqM&input=InsxLCAxLCAyLCAzfSI)

`≡` (`eval`) evaluates the input, which is thankfully specified in Python's set literal syntax. `Σ` then sums the set elements.

Answer (score 2):

## [05AB1E](http://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 9 bytes

```
0E¦¨',¡ÙO
```

[Try it online!](http://05ab1e.tryitonline.net/#code=MEXCpsKoJyzCocOZTw&input=ezEyLDEyLDEzLDEzLDE0LDE0fQ)

**Explanation**

```
0          # push 0
 E         # push evaluated input
  ¦¨       # remove brackets
    ',¡    # split on ","
       Ù   # remove duplicates
        O  # sum
```

`0E` is needed as sum doesn't work on an empty list.

Comment: Gahhh... I didn't realize the challenge assumed the language would use `{` and `}` so I did `Ù0¸˜O`

Comment: @carusocomputing: Yeah, that input format isn't very good for 05AB1E. I started out with a list as well before I noticed the wording :/

Comment: Why doesn't sum work on an empty list?

Comment: @Cyoce: There seem to be a bug in the interpreter. Interestingly, sum do work on a list of empty lists.

Answer (score 2):

### Pyke, <s>9</s> 4 bytes

```
F )s
```

[Try it here!](http://pyke.catbus.co.uk/?code=F+%29s&input=%7B1%2C2%2C3%2C3%7D)

Yes, I have to spend 3 bytes converting a set to a list because Pyke's sum function errors out on sets.

The space is required because the default behavior for a for-loop in Pyke is to print out the arguments

Answer (score 1):

## PHP, 34 Bytes

```
<?=array_sum(array_unique($argv));
```

Answer (score 1):

## Octave, 29 bytes

```
@(x)sum(unique([eval(x){:}]))
```

This creates an anonymous function named `ans` can be called using `ans('{1, 2, 3}')`.

[Online demo](http://ideone.com/MMGDG5)

**Explanation**

The `eval(x)` converts the input string into a cell array of numbers. The `[x{:}]` converts the cell array of numbers into a normal array of numbers. Then we compute the `unique` elements and `sum` the result.

Answer (score 1):

## Ruby, 36 bytes

```
$><<eval(gets.scan(/-?\d+/).uniq*?+)
```

Search for all unique "integer-looking" strings in the input and join this list on the string `+`, then evaluate the resulting string and print the result.

Answer (score 1):

## BASH + CoreUtils + sed + bc <strike>75 68</strike> 50 bytes

Saved a bunch thanks to Digital Trauma and seshoumara

```
sed '/{}/c0
s:[}{,]:\n:g'|sort -u|xargs|tr \  +|bc
```

Comment: `tr , \\n`, etc

Comment: @DigitalTrauma Thanks for the help. My BASH answers usually turn into a learning experience instead of a really well golfed answer.

Comment: You can merge `sed` and `tr` in one `sed` command and use `xargs` at the end, saving 13 bytes: `sed 's:[}{]::g;y:,:\n:;/^$/c0'|sort -u|xargs|tr \  +|bc`. There are two spaces before `+`. For a different way to shorten it further see [my answer](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/95587/sum-the-unique-numbers-in-a-list/95771#95771).

Answer (score 1):

## Mathematica, <s>8</s> 9 bytes

```
Tr@*Union
```

`Union` deletes duplicates (and sorts), and `Tr` totals a list. A rare case when Mathematica can actually compete with golfing languages!

Comment: `Tr@Union` by itself is `Tr[Union]`, which does not do anything. (e.g. `f=Tr@Union; f[{1,2,1}]`) You may want `Tr@*Union`.

Comment: I see your point and you're probably right. But just to clarify for me: `Tr@Union[{1,2,1}]` does work correctly, while `f=Tr@Union; f[{1,2,1}]` does not. Why does that imply (according to community standards) that `Tr@Union` isn't acceptable?

Comment: @GregMartin [By meta consensus](http://meta.ppcg.lol/a/7615), any unnamed functions must be able to be captured into a name; by that logic, `f=(Tr@Union); f[{1,2,1}]` would have to be valid.

Comment: Excellent link. Thank you for taking the time to teach me! :)

Answer (score 1):

## Perl, 28 bytes

Includes +1 for `-p`

Give input on STDIN

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -p
s%-?\d*%$a{$&}//=$_+=$&%reg
```

Surprisingly hard to support the empty set and go below 29 bytes

Answer (score 1):

### Bash + coreutils, 38 bytes

```sh
bc<<<0$(tr ,}{ \\n|sort -u|paste -sd+)
```

[**Try it on ideone.com!**](https://ideone.com/Uxn6I8)

**Explanation:** using `{1,2,1,4}` as test case

```sh
        tr ,}{ \\n       # replace commas and braces with newlines (\n1\n2\n1\n4\n)
        |sort -u         # sort and print unique lines (\n1\n2\n4)
        |paste -sd+      # merge lines with '+' as delimiter (+1+2+4)
bc<<<0$(           )     # prepend '0' and calculate sum (7)
```

Note how prepending a '0' will also help to give a correct answer when the input list is empty (`{}`).

**Run examples:**

```sh
me@LCARS:/PPCG$ ./sum_unique.sh <<< "{}"
0
me@LCARS:/PPCG$ ./sum_unique.sh <<< "{3}"
3
me@LCARS:/PPCG$ ./sum_unique.sh <<< "{-5,5,5}"
0
me@LCARS:/PPCG$ ./sum_unique.sh <<< "{12,12,13,13,14,14}"
39
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Zsh](https://www.zsh.org/), <s>41</s> 34 bytes

```sh
<<<$[${${(us:,:)${1/\{}/\}}// /+}]
```

<s>[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##qyrO@J@moanxPy2/SCFTQUOlWqO02ErHStNQXz@6uja2VlNDI0/bNlNTk8vGxkYlOi/2vyZXmoJ6taGOoY4REBrrmNSqg0WgFEgYiGvV/wMA)</s>
[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##qyrO@J@moanx38bGRiVapVqlWqO02ErHSlOl2lA/prpWP6a2Vl9fQV@7Nva/Jleagnq1oY6hjhEQGuuY1KqDRaAUSBiIa9X/AwA)

`${  / / }` is replacement, `${  // / }` is global replacement, `(s:,:)` splits the string on commas, `(u)` keeps the unique elements.

Answer (score 0):

## Groovy (81 Bytes)

```
z={x->Eval.me(x.replaceAll("\\{","\\[").replaceAll("\\}","\\]")).unique().sum()}
```

Try it online:
https://groovyconsole.appspot.com/edit/5074458091978752

*28 Bytes if you Use [] as brackets...*
`z={Eval.me(it).unique().sum()}`

Answer (score 0):

### R, 51 bytes

```
s=scan;sum(unique(s(t=gsub("\\{|}|,"," ",s(,"")))))
```

Answer (score 0):

## Bash + GNU utilities, 54

```
eval printf '0%s\\n' $1|tr -d {}|sort -u|paste -sd+|bc
```

Input is given as a command-line parameter.  Note that the input must be quoted to prevent expansion by the calling shell (this would be handy, and save some bytes, but I feel like that would be cheating a bit).

The input format is mostly a [bash brace expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Brace-Expansion.html), but it doesn't expand as we want it to for a 0 or 1 element list, so a bit more preprocessing is required before piping to `sort -u`.

[Ideone](https://ideone.com/8fb9xy).

Answer (score 0):

## Pyth, 3 bytes

Unfortunately, the sum builtin doesn't work in Pyth with sets.  I have to convert to a list first...

```
s[F
```

Explanation:

```
 [   Construct list
  F  By splatting in the elements of the input
s    Sum up
```

Taking input as a list-type form would actually be a byte shorter:

```
s{
```

Which is the `s`um of the `{`de-duplicated input.

Answer (score 0):

## [Perl 6](https://perl6.org), 29 bytes

```perl6
*.comb(/<[-\d]>+/).unique.sum
```

### Example:

```perl6
# give the Whatever lambda a name for clarity
my &code = *.comb(/<[-\d]>+/).unique.sum;

say code '{1,2,3,4}'; # 10
say code '{5,-5,5}';  # 0
say code '{}';        # 0
```

Answer (score 0):

### C#, 103 bytes

```
(i)=>i[1]=='}'?0:Regex.Match(i,"{(.*)}").Groups[1].Value.Split(',').Select(int.Parse).Distinct().Sum();
```

this challange its pretty pointless really

Answer (score 0):

### [ListSharp](https://github.com/timopomer/ListSharp), 134 bytes

```
STRG s=INPUT[""] AS STRG
SHOW=ROWSPLIT STRG["0"+GETRANGE s FROM [2] TO [s LENGTH-1]] BY [","]<c#.Select(int.Parse).Distinct().Sum()c#>
```